# Numpy cannot store matrix larger than 1GB in memory

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I need to store large matrix of order `20000x20000`. When I try to initialize a matrix of that order Python raises memory error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\harwee\Desktop\Bubble\test_folder\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    a = numpy.ones((x,x),dtype=int)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 183, in ones
    a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
MemoryError
```

My total ram is 8GB and when I check in Taskmanager it shows a memory usage around 1GB. Why is python raising a memory error when Memory is available. Mine is python 32bit version

here is the code I am using

```
import numpy
x= 16200
a = numpy.ones((x,x),dtype=int)
```

Comment: Try with Python 64bit, I think you've reached the allocation limit for 32

Comment: But shouldn't it be 2 gb for 32bit python?

Comment: yeah but if you have other stuff going on it will overload, and also the allocation space needs contiguity, check my answer

Comment: Keep in mind that the usage shown in the monitor might be for your user only, not for other users, including the system user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using 32-bit Python you won't be able to allocate more than ~2GB, if you're doing other things in your code you may be exceeding that limit. Also, I think numpy requires memory allocation to be contiguous, which can be kind of hard for larger blocks.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a limit enforced by Python but rather one of 32 bit processing. There is only so much space in a 32 bit address system. You can remove this restriction by moving to a 64 bit Python installation.